# Activity variable increment while calling again

Tags: android

I have 2 activity

- Tranning Activity
- Question Activity

i have set one integer variable in question activity like :: `int a=0;`at the end of activity i jump from `Question part` to `Training part`.i call from question part to training part `5` time.But confusion is that how can i increment `"a" variable` each time while `Question part` call?

#### Is it possible by this?

```
if(yes)
{  
  how ?
}
else if(no) 
{
   any other Option are there? how?
}
```

### *Update ::*

**confusion ?**
let me explain

#### run project >> tranning is start >> question is start and variable a is 0 >> tranning is start >>question is start and variable a is 1 >> tranning is start >> question is start and variable a is 2 like that .... a is 5

Comment: you want to increment a every time Tranning Activity is called?

Comment: no ! let me explain run>> tranning is start >> question is start and variable `a` is 0 >> tranning is start >>question is start and variable `a` is 1 >> tranning is start >> question is start and variable `a` is 2 like that .... `a`  is 5

Comment: and also i have update my question please consider it

Comment: ok you wanna increment a every time question starts?

Comment: So, what is the problem that you are facing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it should be incremented only for the current run, you can use a `static` field, and increment it in `onCreate()`, or `onResume()`. if it should be incremented even when the application is restarted, you might want to use [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Comment: static is the only way unless you want to mess with sharedpreferences or files

Comment: can you give one simple example?